# Keep getting runtime error - Script out of range- on Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

Trying to pull input from two text boxes using an array and build a message box with the list. Upon opening the form asks "how many names" to add to the list, then holds that number. You then click "Add name" up until the name count hits 5. Then it should have a message box pop up saying the list is full.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim intItems As Integer

Dim strFName() As String, strLName() As String



Private Sub Form_Load()
intItems = Val(InputBox("How many names?", "Name  Count"))
Do While intItems <= 0
MsgBox "Please provide a number greater than 0", vbCritical, "Correct Value 
Required"
intItems = Val(InputBox("How many names do you have?", "Name List"))
Loop
ReDim strFName(intItems - 1)
End Sub


Private Sub cmdAddName_Click()
Dim intI As Integer
If IsNull(Me.txtFirstName.Value) Or IsNull(Me.txtLastName.Value) = True Then
MsgBox "There must be values for both First and Last names", vbCritical, 
"Data Entry Error"
Else
If strFName(intItems - 1) <> "" Then
MsgBox "Sorry, the list is full!"
Me.txtFirstName.Value = Null
Me.txtLastName.Value = Null
Else
For intI = 0 To intItems - 1
If strFName(intI) = "" Then
strFName(intI) = Me.txtFirstName.Value
strLName(intI) = Me.txtLastName.Value
Me.txtFirstName.Value = Null
Me.txtLastName.Value = Null
Exit For
End If
Next
End If
End If
End Sub
```

I get a runtime error "Script out of range" on 'If strFName(intItems - 1) <> "" Then anyone have any ideas as to why?

Comment: Always helps to indent your code when posting - it's much easier for us to see what's going on then.

Comment: On which line do you get the "Subscript out of range" error?

Comment: If strFName(intItems - 1) <> "" Then

Comment: You didn't resize `strLName`

Comment: What is the value of `intItems` when it crashes?  Is it zero?

Comment: How do I resize still keeping the value of intItems?

Comment: ReDim strFName(intItems - 1) as String : ReDim strLName(intItems - 1) as String

Comment: What do you mean "still keeping the value of intItems"?  A `ReDim` won't alter `intItems` - it will retain its value.

Comment: FWIW - I ran your code without getting an error on the `If strFName(intItems - 1) <> ""` line.  (i.e. it didn't crash until it tried to access the undimensioned `strLName` array.)  Are you **sure** it is crashing on the line you say it is crashing on??

Comment: Once I changed--- 
ReDim strFName(intItems - 1) as String : ReDim strLName(intItems - 1) as String-- it began working, but it's not pulling the strLName down to the list. I will try to fix that for a couple more hours without asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to reDim the other array and reset the data type of the array

Comment: But the error is occurring **before** `strLName` is accessed.  (So that may need to be fixed, but it isn't the cause of the problem in the question.)

Comment: just change the line ReDim strFName(intItems - 1) to  
ReDim strFName(intItems - 1) as String : ReDim strLName(intItems - 1) as String

Comment: FWIW, the `As String` part of a `ReDim` is optional.  A `ReDim` cannot change the data type, so VBA makes no attempt to enforce advising the data type again - it uses the data type as per the original `Dim`.